# Curve the Kernel Density Estimate (KDE) in seaborn displot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, displot

When I try to plot my data in the form of histogram using seaborn displot:

```
plot = sns.displot(
    data=z, kde=True, kind="hist", bins=3000, legend=True, aspect=1.8
).set(title='Error Distribution')
```

The curve for KDE is plotted in the form of straight lines instead of curves like here:
[image: Error Distribution]
Is there a way to make the KDE lines cover all the bins of the histogram in a curved manner?

Comment: Can you provide sample data, so we can reconstruct?

Comment: The sample image doesn't seem to correspond to the sample code.  With `bins=3000`, extremely thin bins would be shown. Did you zoom in rather hard?  Also note that  `sns.displot(....)` returns a `FacetGrid`.

Comment: @JohanC
Yes, there were many bins with count close to 0, so I zoomed in near the centre.
I guess that's why the reason for this KDE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of zooming in, you could use the bins to restrict to a certain range (via `binrange=...`). To limit the range of the kde, you can use the `clip` keyword.  Here is an example, first without setting the range:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# first, create some test data
slatm = np.random.normal(-.9, .4, size=(10000, 10)).max(axis=1)
split = np.random.normal(-.1, .1, size=(10000, 10)).max(axis=1)
split[0] = 200  # ad an extreme far value to the dataset
z = pd.DataFrame({'slatm': slatm, 'split': split})

g = sns.displot(data=z, kde=True, kind="hist", bins=3000, legend=True, aspect=1.8)
g.set(title='Error Distribution')
g.ax.set_xlim(-1, 0.5) # zoom in via the x limits
```

[image: displot with zooming in]

Here is how it would look with limiting the ranges for the histogram and the kde:

```py
min_x, max_x = -1, 0.5
g = sns.displot(data=z, kde=True, kind="hist", bins=30, binrange=(min_x, max_x), legend=True, aspect=1.8,
                kde_kws={'clip': (min_x, max_x)})
g.set(title='Error Distribution')
```

[image: sns.displot with limiting the ranges]